# Set number of spaces to indent on a project in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I use WebStorm for multiple projects, and most use 4 spaces for indenting.One project however uses 2 spaces for indenting.

Is there something I can add to the xml files in the `.idea/` directory to make it so when I open this project, it defaults to two spaces instead of the standard 4 spaces?

Comment: Code Style (where such settings are set) can be global (IDE-wide; can be used by any number of projects) or local (project-specific; used by this project only). So .. why don't you use **project-specific Code Style scheme**?

Comment: Other than that: try **EditorConfig plugin** and appropriate `.editorconfig` file (note: settings from such file override your IDE settings).